# Diablo 3 Witch Doctor Base Intelligence difference

Tags: diablo-iii-witch-doctor, diablo-iii-console

I have two level 60 witch doctors.  I'm playing the console version.  One of them has about 16k intelligence with no gear, and the other has about 7k, also with no gear.  Why?  Is it because I leveled the 16k one up at a higher paragon level?  I'm currently paragon 47, and was probably around 15 when I leveled up the first one.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do they have the same skills set?

Comment: Yes, I checked that.

Comment: Did you recently use Soul Harvest with one of them?

Comment: Are you sure it's your Int that's at 16k? The highest primary stat I've seen on a well-geared level 70 character is 5-6k. Even so, stats shouldn't be that high with no gear. I think you start at level 1 with 20 to your primary stat with +3 per level. That should be 200 at level 60. Being Plevel 47 means you probably have 11 points to put into int pushing it up to 255.

Comment: Would you mind puttin a screenshot with the 2 charactaer sheet so we can maybe spot the difference ? To maek a screenshot just press print screen > the screenshot are saved under *My documents > diablo 3 > screenshots*

Comment: @WizLiz They're on console.

Comment: When I get home from work, I can put up any values you like. If someone wants to tell me how to take screen shots off of my TV screen, I'll have a go at that too. But I don't think it has anything to do with gear, and I don't think it's because I'm misreading my screen. I'll try putting the same gear on each of them and seeing what the paperdoll dps is. On the one with 16k, I'm getting about 1250k dps, which is pretty much facemelting everything on Master Level V.  And my gear is pretty good but not great: no trifectas, 4 Zunis, a bonesaber with no socket, crafted shoulders and bracers, etc.

Comment: It looks like the only way you'll be able to take a "screenshot" is to take a picture of the TV screen.

Comment: Now there's an idea.

Comment: @Katustrawfic see for yourself.  Maybe the console works differently; I assume that you're using the PC version since you're talking about level 70.

Comment: @SaintWacko done.  See answer below.

Comment: This must be a bug.

Comment: What happens if you put the gear back on? What are the values then?

Comment: The lower one has about 500k dps, and the higher one about 1250k dps. That's with about 18k int, and reasonably good gear, like no trifectas and maybe half BIS. Needless to say, she is facemelting everything at ML5 with the exception of the uber Siegebreaker. I blew up the dogs on him and oneshotted myself with his reflect. :)  For that one, I have to burn down Zoltan with the Bats of Instant Death and then ping the Siegebreaker with firebombs while the animals tank him, all the while keeping an eye on my life.  I just picked up a Skorn tho, so I might have enough lifesteal if I use it.

Comment: It isn't clear from the shots, but I conjecture that the smarter one is female and the one with lower intelligence is male : )

Comment: That's correct.  :)

Comment: I haven't played the console version, but is paragon level shared over all characters or is it specific per character? If it is specific per character, what is the paragon level of the high intelligence one?

Comment: @horatio : turns out that it is indeed a bug.  See Ozmah's answer below.

Comment: @Arperum : Paragon level is shared by all characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some digging regarding this situation and it seems that there was a bug not that long ago in the console version regarding Set bonuses, here's a video that shows the bug:

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zuh3KEfoZKA)

This video shows how you get a 100 Vit bonus by wearing two pieces of a set, you logout and login and you get another 100 Vit increase due to the Set bonus, and even if you unequip the items, you still keep the bonuses in your base stats.

According to the console [hotfix log](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/9882388986) from Blizzard, this bug was fixed in September of last year and it mentions that it just fixed the new ocurrences but did not fix the affected characters. All affected characters were set to the right statuses by the 1.0.2 Patch release 10/01/2013, [these](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/10137253879) are the patch notes.

This is the closest thing I found or I could think of that could have affected your Witch Doctor, as it seems consistent enough, but given the timeframe, the only way this could still happen to you is if you hadn't added that patch and kept playing offline (which I've no idea if it's possible in the console version).

Comment: This is very interesting.  I've never played online specifically, and don't know if patches get downloaded automatically.  (Do you?)  I bought the game probably just before 10/1/2013.

Comment: In PS3, whenever you're online (logged in the PSN) and start a game, the system prompts you to update to the latests patch of the game.

Comment: You found it!  I have Zunimassa's stuff, which gives +130 int.  I quit and started again, and sure enough my int was incremented by 130.  Great stuff, Ozmah, and thank you.

Comment: I use XBox 360, and haven't coughed up for XBox online.  I guess I'll have to do that to get the patches.

Comment: Not a problem @BobRodes always happy to help.

Comment: @BobRodes: patches are usually available without being a "gold member" AFAIK. Maybe try setting up a silver account first.

Answer (score 1):

There must have been something you have done to your characters, as per definition you start out with 10 points in your primary stat when you create a character and get an increase of 3 per level in your primary stat, this means that at lvl 60 you have gained 59 levels resulting in an increase of your primary stat by 59*3 = 177 points meaning you should have 187 points in your intelligence in total.

I am not sure if the console version of the game still works with the old paragon system in which you gain stats, magic find and gold find per paragon level but if this is the case you should be getting the normal stat increase as mentioned above. (3 primary stat points per level). This is different in the paragon 2.0 system where you can assign the points you get per paragon level to different stats, meaning if you put points in your main stat it increases by 5 per point put in the chosen stat.

All this should make it clear that it is impossible to get those statistics you mentioned without wearing gear. If there is someone with a better explanation for this phenomenon I would like to read it.

I hereby hope to have informed you well enough.

Comment: The above answer is just speculation though since you haven't shown us your entire screen and with that the other statistics such as toughness etc. We don't see what your character and/or follower is equipped with or if you are playing with other people which also affects your statistics.

Comment: See Ozmah's answer below. It's the correct one, clearly. As for the other details, I didn't put them in because I found they were irrelevant. Here's my reasoning. Stats: the only stats that increase base int do so for a little while and then revert, so not relevant. Gear: there isn't any gear combination I know of that can buff your int by 8k and keep you at 221 vit. Other players: I play solo, but there isn't any combination of buffs from other players that could give the stats pictured anyway. If you find a flaw in my reasoning, please let me know.